# Return list from Spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, response, httpresponse

I want to return List from Spring rest api:

```
@GetMapping("merchant_country")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMerchantCountry() {
        return ok(Contracts.getSerialversionuid());
    }
```

I want to get the content from here:

```
private Map<String, Object> getCountryNameCodeList() {

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        Map<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            list.put(obj.getDisplayCountry().toString(), obj.getCountry());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

How I can map the result?

Comment: you want to return map or list? there is no relation between two methods?

Comment: ok, how I can return getCountryNameCodeList as map when I call GET merchant_country from angular code?

Comment: Could't you just set the list as a value of the map then?

Comment: this is good place to start https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ @PeterPenzov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ResponseEntity` when you need more control over the HTTP response (e.g. setting HTTP headers, providing a different status code).

In other cases, you can simply return a POJO (or a collection), and Spring will handle everything else for you.

```
class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @GetMapping("merchant_country")
    public Map<String, Object> getMerchantCountry() {
        return service.getCountryNameCodeList();
    }

}

class Service {

    public Map<String, Object> getCountryNameCodeList() { ... }

}
```

`Locate#getCountry` returns `String`, so it could be `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, you have to create ResponseEntity as suggested by Andrew

```
class controller{
@Autowired
    private Service service;
@GetMapping("merchant_country")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getMerchantCountry() {
        return service.getCountryNameCodeList();
    }`enter code here`
}
class service
{
private ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getCountryNameCodeList() {

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        Map<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            list.put(obj.getDisplayCountry().toString(), obj.getCountry());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```